# How do I transform origin coordinates of labels on scaled image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scale, transformation

I have an app that generates an image of what's on the screen. I have a label on the screen with origin:0,148 and dimension 89.5x37.5. The screen resolution is 375x667 and the generated image is 675x1200. How do I correctly determine the origin and dimension of the label when scaling from 376x667 to 675x1200?

The scale factor is 1.8.

origin = (0,148)
dimension = 89.5 by 37.5

Transformed origin = ???

Transformed dimension = 89.5*1.8 by 37.5*1.8

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat scaleFactor = 1.8;
CGRect lblRct = myLabel.frame;
lblRct.origin.x *= scaleFactor; //unnecessary really, as it is 0
lblRct.origin.y *= scaleFactor;
lblRct.size.height *= scaleFactor;
lblRct.size.width *= scaleFactor;

UIFont *font = myLabel.font;
CGFloat ptSz = font.pointSize;
ptSz *= scaleFactor;

UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: lblRct];
newLabel.font = [font fontWithPointSize: ptSz ];
newLabel.text = myLabel.text;


/// render your image into a CGContextRef

[newLabel.layer renderInContext: cxt];
```